# How do I tweak my bash script below for searching sub directories

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, directory-listing

I have a directory with files in the following strcuture:

```
HomeTransaction1/Date1/transactionfile1.txt
HomeTransaction1/Date1/transactionfile1.xls
HomeTransaction1/Date1/transactionfile2.xls
HomeTransaction1/Date1/transactionfile2.txt
HomeTransaction1/Date1/transactionfile3.txt
HomeTransaction1/Date2/transactionfile1.txt
HomeTransaction1/Date3/transactionfile2.txt
HomeTransaction1/Date3/transactionfile3.txt
HomeTransaction2/Date1/transactionfile1.txt
HomeTransaction2/Date1/transactionfile2.txt
HomeTransaction3/Date1/transactionfile3.txt
```

I'm trying to get for a specific thing in the transaction files that end in .txt so I'm trying to come up with a bash script to achieve this. Conceptually, this is my thought process.

**A** - List each folder in the current directory. I this example, it'll be HomeTransaction1, HomeTransaction2 and HomeTransaction3

**B** - for each folder in B list all the folders(the Date folders)

**C** - for each folder in step B, run "grep " for files with .txt extension

This is what I have come up with so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

for FILE in `ls -l`
do
    if test -d $FILE && (startswith "HomeTrasaction") //I want to add a condition to check that the directory name and starts with "HomeTrasaction"
    then
      cd $FILE     // example cd to 'HomeTransaction1' directory
       echo "In HomeTransaction directory $FILE"
       for SUB_FILE in `ls -l` 
        do
         cd $SUB_FILE //example cd to 'Date1'
                echo "In Date directory $FILE"
           for TS_FILES in ($find . -print | grep .txt)
             grep "text-to-search" $SUB_FILE
      
    fi
done
```

I appreciate any help in finalizing my script. Thank you.

Comment: There are a *lot* of syntax and scripting errors here; I'd recommend [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net), but you might have to give it the script a bit at a time, so it's not overwhelmed and confused. Nonetheless... would `grep "text-to-search" HomeTransaction*/*/*.txt` do it (maybe with some additional flags to `grep` to control filename reporting)?

Comment: Short way `tree HomeTransaction[0-9]*` You will have to determine what you want to exclude and then work with `grep -v 'regex'` to remove the unwanted extensions.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is actually pretty simple

```
find ./HomeTrasaction* -iname "*.txt" -exec grep -i "phrase" {} \;
```

find ./HomeTrasaction* - search each directory that start with this phrase, in the current directory.

-iname "*.txt" - for each file that ends with .txt

-exec grep -i "phrase" {} ; - grep for the word "phrase"

If this is still not clear "man find" :)